# How can I turn record array from arff file into ndarray?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, arff

[ARFF documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.arff.loadarff.html) tells me that my file is being read as a record array but I can't seem to convert it to ndarray like a normal record array. There should be 11055 examples with 31 features.

```
>>> dataset.shape
(11055,)
>>> dataset[0]
(b'1', b'1', b'1', b'1', b'1', b'-1', b'1', b'1', b'-1', b'1', b'1', b'1', b'1', b'0', b'0', b'-1', b'1', b'1', b'0', b'1', b'1', b'1', b'1', b'1', b'1', b'1', b'1', b'1', b'0', b'1', b'1')
>>> dataset.dtype
dtype([('having_IP_Address', 'S2'), ('URL_Length', 'S2'), ('Shortining_Service', 'S2'), ('having_At_Symbol', 'S2'), ('double_slash_redirecting', 'S2'), ('Prefix_Suffix', 'S2'), ('having_Sub_Domain', 'S2'), ('SSLfinal_State', 'S2'), ('Domain_registeration_length', 'S2'), ('Favicon', 'S2'), ('port', 'S2'), ('HTTPS_token', 'S2'), ('Request_URL', 'S2'), ('URL_of_Anchor', 'S2'), ('Links_in_tags', 'S2'), ('SFH', 'S2'), ('Submitting_to_email', 'S2'), ('Abnormal_URL', 'S2'), ('Redirect', 'S1'), ('on_mouseover', 'S2'), ('RightClick', 'S2'), ('popUpWidnow', 'S2'), ('Iframe', 'S2'), ('age_of_domain', 'S2'), ('DNSRecord', 'S2'), ('web_traffic', 'S2'), ('Page_Rank', 'S2'), ('Google_Index', 'S2'), ('Links_pointing_to_page', 'S2'), ('Statistical_report', 'S2'), ('Result', 'S2')])
```

Basically, I am trying to turn this record array stored in `dataset` into a ndarray and reshape it to match the vector dimensions. The problem seems to be that the ndarray that I am left with is a list of objects with that long record dtype rather than a list of lists. I am just not sure how to convert that dtype into a list.

```
from scipy.io import arff
import urllib.request
import io
import numpy as np

# this just reads the arff from its URL 
url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00327/Training%20Dataset.arff"
ftpstream = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
dataset, meta = arff.loadarff(io.StringIO(ftpstream.read().decode('utf-8')))

num_features = len(meta.names())
num_examples = dataset.shape[0]
dataset.view(np.ndarray).reshape(num_examples, num_features)
```

This last line causes error `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 11055 into shape (11055,31)`.

What I am ultimately looking to end up with is a ndarray with shape(11055,31) and a numeric dtype.

You can find the data [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00327/Training%20Dataset.arff). But here is what the file looks like:

```
@relation phishing

@attribute having_IP_Address  { -1,1 }
@attribute URL_Length   { 1,0,-1 }
@attribute Shortining_Service { 1,-1 }
@attribute having_At_Symbol   { 1,-1 }
@attribute double_slash_redirecting { -1,1 }
@attribute Prefix_Suffix  { -1,1 }
@attribute having_Sub_Domain  { -1,0,1 }
@attribute SSLfinal_State  { -1,1,0 }
@attribute Domain_registeration_length { -1,1 }
@attribute Favicon { 1,-1 }
@attribute port { 1,-1 }
@attribute HTTPS_token { -1,1 }
@attribute Request_URL  { 1,-1 }
@attribute URL_of_Anchor { -1,0,1 }
@attribute Links_in_tags { 1,-1,0 }
@attribute SFH  { -1,1,0 }
@attribute Submitting_to_email { -1,1 }
@attribute Abnormal_URL { -1,1 }
@attribute Redirect  { 0,1 }
@attribute on_mouseover  { 1,-1 }
@attribute RightClick  { 1,-1 }
@attribute popUpWidnow  { 1,-1 }
@attribute Iframe { 1,-1 }
@attribute age_of_domain  { -1,1 }
@attribute DNSRecord   { -1,1 }
@attribute web_traffic  { -1,0,1 }
@attribute Page_Rank { -1,1 }
@attribute Google_Index { 1,-1 }
@attribute Links_pointing_to_page { 1,0,-1 }
@attribute Statistical_report { -1,1 }
@attribute Result  { -1,1 }


@data
-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1
1,1,1,1,1,-1,0,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,0,-1,-1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,0,-1,1,1,1,-1
1,0,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,0,-1,-1
1,0,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,0,0,-1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1
1,0,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,0,0,-1,1,1,0,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,0,-1,1,1,1,1
-1,0,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,0,0,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1
1,0,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,0,-1,-1
1,0,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,0,-1,1,0,1,-1
1,0,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,0,1,-1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,0,1,1
1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,0,1,-1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,-1,0,-1,1,0,1,-1
1,1,1,1,1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,1,-1,0,0,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1
1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,0,-1,-1
-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,0,0,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,0,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,0,1,-1
1,1,-1,1,1,-1,0,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,0,-1,1,1,1,-1
1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1
1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,0,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,0,-1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,0,1,-1
1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,1,-1,0,-1,1,1,-1,-1
```

Comment: You should check `dataset.dtype` rather than `type(dataset)` or `type(dataset[0])`. The former will give you the numpy datatypes of your record. The latter two will just tell you the Python type, which is either an ndarray or scalar.

Comment: Ok so Python reads the elements as scalars in the ndarray which is where the void comes from I guess. `dataset.dtype` gives me the types and column name of each element in that tuple-like struct as in a record array. So: `dtype([('having_IP_Address', 'S2'),('URL_Length', 'S2'), ... ])`. Any ideas as far as how I can turn each of these objects into a numpy array?

Comment: Please edit the question with the full dtype. You already have a numpy array. Each element has the fields named in the dtype. Looks like there are a bunch of two character strings...

Comment: Ok done. I am not invested in the field names. I am really just looking for a ndarray containing `array([[-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1], ... [-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,0,-1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1]])` as some numeric dtype and there really seems to be very little flexibility with how the arff is read.

Comment: Looks like the file is in a text format. Could you post the first 20 or so lines here? The documentation is actually pretty clear. I'm just trying to figure out why your data isn't being loaded as numbers.

Comment: This is the link: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00327/Training%20Dataset.arff . I'll edit question with the some of the file. The first ~31 lines are the attributes of the data.

Comment: @MadPhysicist ok edited question with a sample of the file-- it is being read from URL. Thank you by the way.

Comment: I've asked this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53954147/2988730. Now I can write youa proper answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for distilling my actual question. I really appreciate it!

Another clumsy potential work around I've found is that the data can be stored in a DataFrame and `astype(int)` will work on the DataFrame whereas it gives `Can't cast from structure to non-structure, except if the structure only has a single field.` error on the ndarray. Then I can just grab the df.values. But obviously that's pretty ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the file, we can see that all the fields are of categorical type, rather than numeric. Aside from that, your array is a regular `ndarray` with a complicated dtype. Since that's not something you can change, you will have to convert the structure and dtype of your array. The neatest approach (although not the most efficient) would be

```
dataset = np.array(dataset.tolist(), dtype=np.int8)
```

`tolist` will convert the array into a list of tuples, which the simple dtype `int8` will then cause to be reassembled into a regular array.

This question was the basis for [converting numpy array of string fields to numerical format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53954147/2988730).

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you understand why pandas would let me do `.astype(int)` but numpy returns the error `Can't cast from structure to non-structure, except if the structure only has a single field.` with `.astype(int)` ?

Comment: Because in numpy, you have a complex structure in each element. It's pure coincidence that all the elements of the structure are of the same type. Pandas can handle each field as a distinct column and apply a different transformation to it as necessary.