# converting numpy array of string fields to numerical format

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of strings grouped into three fields:

```
x = np.array([(-1, 0, 1),
              (-1, 1, 0),
              (0, 1, -1),
              (0, -1, 1)],
             dtype=[('a', 'S2'),
                    ('b', 'S2'),
                    ('c', 'S2')])
```

I would like to convert to a numerical array (of type `np.int8` for a preference, but not required), shaped 4x3, instead of the fields.

My general approach is to transform into a 4x3 array of type 'S2', then use `astype` to make it numerical. The only problem is that the only approach I can think of involves both `view` and `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`, which doesn't seem like a very robust solution:

```
y = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x.view(dtype='S2'),
                                    shape=(4, 3), strides=(6, 2))
z = y.astype(np.int8)
```

This works for the toy case shown here, but I feel like there must be a simpler way to unpack an array with fields all having the same dtype. What is a more robust alternative?

Comment: Using lists is the most robust way of converting a structured array to a simple dtype one: `np.array(x.tolist(),'int8')`

Comment: @hpaulij. I'd probably select that answer, although it bothers me that I now need a third copy of the data.

Comment: Why S2 in the first place? How are you reading this in?

Comment: @Andy. https://stackoverflow.com/q/53953116/2988730. I asked this question to shamelessly rip off the answer hpaulj provided.

Comment: @hpaulj. I've used the technique you suggest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954336/2988730

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of numpy 1.16 added `structured_to_unstructured` which solves this purpose:

```
from numpy.lib.recfunctions import structured_to_unstructured
y = structured_to_unstructured(x)  # 2d array of 'S2'
z = y.astype(np.int8)
```

In previous version of numpy, you can combine `x.data` and `np.frombuffer` to create another array from the same data in memory without having to use strides. It doesn't bring performance gain though, as the computation is driven by the casting from `S2` to `int8`.

```py
n = 1000

def f1(x):
    y = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x.view(dtype='S2'),
                                        shape=(n, 3),
                                        strides=(6, 2))
    return y.astype(np.int8)

def f2(x):
    y = np.frombuffer(x.data, dtype='S2').reshape((n, 3))
    return y.astype(np.int8)


x = np.array([(i%3-1, (i+1)%3-1, (i+2)%3-1)
              for i in xrange(n)],
             dtype='S2,S2,S2')

z1 = f1(x)
z2 = f2(x)
assert (z1==z2).all()
```

Comment: I'm not super worried about the performance. The conversion will inevitably dominate as you say. It's just manipulating field arrays that I'm uncertain about.

Comment: For me stride tricks is a bit like regex. I find myself with two problems at the end sometimes.

Comment: added `structured_to_unstructured` in numpy>=1.16 which does exactly what you're looking for!